# Как можно сразу же заменять Toast

Tags: java, android

Как можно заменить Toast в любой момент даже если он только появился и как можно его убирать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(context, "Some test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
toast.cancel(); //убрать тост
toast.setText("Another text"); //установить новый текст
```

Все это описано в [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) или [тут](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)